# failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi, picamera

I am working on Raspberry Pi, and I have connected my Picam and tested it, it is running correct. But when my application it gives me error of.

**ERROR:**

```
Opening ASL Model!
/home/pi/Desktop/ASL/ASLClassifier.dat
SVM Loaded successfully..
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x6a221df0 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
[2021-05-10 12:02:57,924] ERROR in app: Exception on /camera [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 122, in camera
    cap=PiCamera(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2021 12:02:57] "POST /camera HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**CAMERA ROUTE**

```
# Camera route
@app.route("/camera", methods = ['POST'])
def camera():
    print("Opening ASL Model!")
    try:
        direct = cwd + "/ASLClassifier.dat"
        print(direct)
        model=st.load(direct)
        print("SVM Loaded successfully..")
    except:
        model=st.trainSVM(17)
    
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap=PiCamera(0)
    camera=PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 32
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    rgbFrame = PiRGBArray(camera, size = camera.resolution)
    frame1 = captureProcessFrame(camera, rgbFrame, 5)
    frameCount = 0
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    text= " "

    temp=0
    previouslabel=None # Past label
    previousText=" " # Past text
    label = None # current label
    
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True): 
        stream = frame.array # store frame input as array
        rawCapture.truncate(0) # take optional size
        img=stream # store stream as temp img
        cv2.rectangle(img, (300,300), (100,100), (0,255,0),0) # create rectangle one screen
        img1 = img[100:300, 100:300] # image stream ratio
        img_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB) # color format settings
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_ycrcb,(11,11),0)
        skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 138, 67)) # color spaces min
        skin_ycrcb_max = np.array((255, 173, 133)) # color spaces max
        mask = cv2.inRange(blur, skin_ycrcb_min, skin_ycrcb_max) 
        imgres,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # track motion points
        cnt=ut.getMaxContour(contours,4000) #store total motion points
        if cnt is not None: # is there something there?
            gesture,label=ut.getGestureImg(cnt,img1,mask,model)   
            if(label!=None): 
                if(temp==0): # if temp is 0
                    previouslabel=label # last label now label
                elif previouslabel==label: # still same gesture?
                    previouslabel=label # track again
                    temp+=1 # increse temp gesture count
                else: # otherwise
                    temp=0 # temp gesture back to 0
                if(temp==40): # has it been on screen for 40 temp counts?
                    if(label=='P'): # create sentence space if user does P
                        label=" " # lable space
                        text= text + label # add results to text
                    if(label=='Q'): # Wipe with Q(QUIT)
                        words = re.split(" +",text) # split result
                        words.pop() # push text off
                        text = " ".join(words) # fresh text
                        #text=previousText
                print(text) # print out your last gestures before quiting

            #cv2.imshow('PredictedGesture',gesture)              
            cv2.putText(img,label,(50,150), font,8,(0,125,155),2)  
            cv2.putText(img,text,(50,450), font,3,(0,0,255),2)
            
        cv2.imshow('Frame',img) # show on screen
        #cv2.imshow('Mask',mask)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF # wait for q to quit
        if key == ord("q"): # is Q?
            #cap.release()        
            cv2.destroyAllWindows() # close OpenCV session
            camera.close()
            break # stop while

    return render_template("index.html")
```

My Pi cam is enabled and no other application is using it but I am still getting this error. Kindly help me, below is my FLask API code which I am using to trigger the Pi cam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my Pi cam, I wasn't configuring it properly and after doing that I updated my firm using,

```
sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this after complete your camera capture operation. This may stop the background running of the camera:

```
camera.close()
```

Comment: I am using a Pi3 for 2 months taking photos each 3 o 4 minutes during daytime. I have around 9000 photos and yesterday same issue happens to me. I rebooted and after some hours it came again. I also haven't `camera.close`, just `camera.stop`.  I rebooted again and added `close`. It is strange that that started happening after a long time using the script

Answer (score 0):

Update the firmware and try again, it might work

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: I have tried sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. You have to close the camera. If you look at camera after getting error it will be still running beacuse the thread in the process is not ended yet.

Comment: This wasn't the case as I started it for the first time and still got the error it means no thread is in the process.